# Проблема с запуском своих приложений в windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-basic, windows-8

Имеется машина с windows 8.1 x64 и Visual Studio Community. При попытке запустить релиз версию проекта Windows Forms (Visual Basic) вне среды процесс намертво зависает, ошибок не выдает. Такая ситуация с любым типом проектов Visual Studio. Компилируется без ошибок, пробовал создавать просто пустой проект с одной только формой, результат тот же. 
На втором компьютере с Win7 x64 все запускается с флешки без проблем. Подозреваю какие-то проблемы с .NET Framework, но нагуглить что-то внятное не удалось.

Comment: Тут вроде была аналогичная проблема и вылечилась отключением антивируса, если я ничего не путаю.

Comment: Это характерно именно для Win8? На втором компьютере антивирус точно такой же. И с запуском любых других программ проблем в принципе нет. Не работают только собранные в студии.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Вы были правы. Добавил в исключения антивируса папку с проектом и все заработало. Спасибо! Никак не ожидал что проблема может быть с антивирусом

Comment: Ну вообще это довольно странно что он тупо блокирует софт без каких либо сообщений. Что за АВ кстати?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Avast. Нашел на их форуме поддержки несколько тем с похожей проблемой. Начиная с версии Visual Studio 2012. На 10 все работает. Правда там у людей Avast вообще удалял все неизвестные ему .exe которые генерирует среда.

Comment: Кросавчеги, чо: без уведомления что-то блокировать или удалять...